# LZW Compression In Lua

Tags: function, dictionary, lua, compression, lzw

Here is the Pseudocode for Lempel-Ziv-Welch Compression.

```
 pattern = get input character
 while ( not end-of-file ) {
     K = get input character
     if ( <<pattern, K>> is NOT in 
             the string table ){
         output the code for pattern
         add <<pattern, K>> to the string table
         pattern = K
     }
     else { pattern = <<pattern, K>> }
 }
 output the code for pattern
 output EOF_CODE
```

I am trying to code this in Lua, but it is not really working. Here is the code I modeled after an LZW function in Python, but I am getting an "attempt to call a string value" error on line 8.

```
 function compress(uncompressed)

 local dict_size = 256
 local dictionary = {}

 w = ""
 result = {}
 for c in uncompressed do
  -- while c is in the function compress
     local wc = w + c
     if dictionary[wc] == true then
         w = wc
     else
         dictionary[w] = ""
         -- Add wc to the dictionary.
         dictionary[wc] = dict_size
         dict_size = dict_size + 1
         w = c
    end
 -- Output the code for w.
 if w then
   dictionary[w] = ""
 end
 end
 return dictionary
 end

 compressed = compress('TOBEORNOTTOBEORTOBEORNOT')
 print (compressed)
```

I would really like some help either getting my code to run, or helping me code the LZW compression in Lua. Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [LZW Data Compression In Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11745265)

Comment: possible duplicate of [LZW Data Compression In Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745265/lzw-data-compression-in-lua)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `uncompressed` is a string, you'll need to use something like this to iterate over it:

```
for i = 1, #uncompressed do
  local c = string.sub(uncompressed, i, i)
  -- etc
end
```

There's another issue on line 10; `..` is used for string concatenation in Lua, so this line should be `local wc = w .. c`.

You may also want to read [this](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.6.html) with regard to the performance of string concatenation.  Long story short, it's often more efficient to keep each element in a table and return it with `table.concat()`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new with this... But what should go after the --etc comment? Thank you so much!

Comment: It runs with no errors! Thank you! My small issue now is that it is printing "table: 0x7861e7f0"... thanks!

Comment: Also, I tried changing the 'return dictionary' to 'return w', and moved it inside of the for loop, but now it is only printing "T".

Comment: `return table.concat(dictionary)` will output it as a string.

Comment: Now it's printing "", nothing.

Comment: A) make sure you move it back out of the loop  (B) why do you keep clearing out the dictionary (dictionary[w] = "") ?

Comment: I moved it out of the loop, still the same thing. Removing the if statement where I clear the dictionary doesn't change it. It still is printing "T".

Answer (score 2):

You should also take a look [here](http://www.wowace.com/addons/libcompress/files/39-r49-release-nolib/) to download the source for a high-performance LZW compression algorithm in Lua...

Comment: Ah, but it shows some nice Lua techniques that may be useful.

Comment: Also note that its license is GPL version 2