# LZW Data Compression In Lua

Tags: function, dictionary, lua, compression, lzw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LZW Compression In Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744573/lzw-compression-in-lua)

Here is my code for compressing data in Lua using the LZW compression method. My problem is that the function is returning the character 'T', instead of returning the full compressed string 'TOBEORNOTTOBEORNOT'. Thanks!

```
 function compress(uncompressed)
 local dict_size = 256
 local dictionary = {}
   w = ""
   result = {}
     for i = 1, #uncompressed do
       local c = string.sub(uncompressed, i, i)
       local wc = w .. c
       if dictionary[wc] == true then
           w = wc
       else
           dictionary[w] = ""
           dictionary[wc] = dict_size
           dict_size = dict_size + 1
           w = c
       end
     if w then
       dictionary[w] = ""
     end
     return w
   end
 end

 compressed = compress('TOBEORNOTTOBEORTOBEORNOT')
 print(compressed)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [LZW Compression In Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11744573)

Comment: Two questions about the same algorithm, strangely using the same sample text to compress. Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hint: you `return w` in the for loop

**EDIT** some explanation

If you return your result in the loop, then the loop will do only one iteration. At the end of the first iteration, your function will finish. That makes no sense. So your return statement should come after the for loop.

Also, it is suspicious that you declare a variable `result = {}` and then you never use it.

So I suggest you put your return statement after the loop and you print the value of your variables at the end of in each iteration (you'd put the print statements where you have the `return` now), so you can see what is really happening.

Comment: The 'return w' is in the for loop, no?

Comment: `return` statement should come after the loop, see the explanation I added to the answer

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I put a few print statements, and it is printing what I want. 'WC' prints out, "T TO OB BE EO OR RN NO OT TO OB BE EO OR RN NO OT T". Now that I have this, what should be returned?

Comment: if `print(w)` prints `TOBEORNOTTOBEORNOT` at the end of the last iteration, then do `return w` after the loop.

Comment: Putting print(w) inside of the for loop, after the if statement ends - prints "TOBEORNOTTOBEORNOT nil" (each letter on separate line). If I put return w in the same place as the print(w), after the if statements ends inside of the for loop, it only prints "T". Putting the return w outside/after the for loop prints the same "T".

Comment: Do I want an answer like this? Returning dictionary inside the for loop returns this 'table: 0x7866c310'