# Decompressing LZW in Lua

Tags: lua, compression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LZW Compression In Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744573/lzw-compression-in-lua)

I would really love help from anyone on how to do LZW decompression in Lua. I've been looking around the internet, and all I've really found are articles on compression. Help?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you need to do it with native Lua code, or can you use an extension module (i.e. shared library dynamically loaded via Lua's module system)?

Comment: [Here's a native implementation (written for WoW).](http://www.wowace.com/addons/libcompress/files/39-r49-release-nolib/)

Comment: Three separate questions about LZW compression in Lua? Why does it sound like someone gave people a homework assignment on this?

Comment: I need it with the native Lua code. This isn't a homework assignment, I was just surfing the web and came upon LZW compression, but I was just interested to know if there was a decompression program for it.